# Create file after transferring via SFTP

Tags: bash, sftp

How can I automatically create an empty file with the same name as the source but append ".transferred " extension after SFTP transfer is completed successfully for a specific user?

## EXAMPLE

```
scp /home/somefile.txt someuser@someserver:/somedirectory/somefile.txt
```

Once this transfer is done I would want somefile.txt.transferred on the source server.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using bash, you can do this:

```
# The following line defines the name of the file you are scp-ing to destination
FILE=somefile.txt

# Now you do the scp
scp /home/$FILE someuser@someserver:/somedirectory/$FILE

# Adding a temporary variable so that we can define name of the file to be touched
TRANS=".transferred"
TOUCH_FILE="$FILE$TRANS"

#Now we create the empty file that you wanted
touch /home/$TOUCH_FILE

#Confirm that it got created
ls -l /home/$TOUCH_FILE
```

Comment: Thanks @Mamun. That would work, however I would need to change the script for every file I transfer. What I'm looking for is to have this running for every file that is being transferred from a specific folder.